# QT WebEngine & JavaScript failed to load .PNG image

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5.5

My work Environment : **Qt 5.8 MSVC2015 64bit, Windows 7 64 bit, Web engine, JavaScript.**

In  in QT code i am loading image, converting data into QByteArray & transfering back to JavaScript. So javaScript can render image. **But JavaScript failed to load .png images, any clue what I am missing here ?**

QT .h file code  :

```
Q_INVOKABLE QByteArray GetTile();
```

QT .cpp file code  :

```
QByteArray ExportedObject::GetTile()
{
QByteArray arr;
QFile imageFile("D:\\2.png");
arr = imageFile.readAll();
imageFile.close();
return arr;
}
```

JavaScript code :

```
var myRetValue;  
myRetValue = window.interface.GetTile(function(returnValue) {
        return returnValue;
    });
alert (myRetValue);
document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + returnValue;
```

Why returnValue not get stored in myRetValue ?

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: I must admit, I don't know much about the WebEngine, but I find it interesting that you define in `C++` a function without parameters and then you pass a JS-function to it.

Comment: When I assign image buffer to  document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src , it don't load any image.

Comment: @derM:  var myRetValue;  
myRetValue = window.interface.GetTile(function(returnValue) {
 return returnValue;
});
alert (myRetValue);

Why myRetValue don't get returnValue ?

Comment: @derM: thanks, I have changed question after you comments.

Comment: `GetTile()` as defined in your C++-code does not seem to take a parameter. So what is that JS-function you try to pass to it supposed to do?

Comment: Don't you get a message reading something like: `QIODevice::read (QFile, "...png"): device not open`? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#reading-files-directly - that's at least what I get, when I don't open the file before reading.

Answer (score 0):

@derM: thanks lot for inputs. Fix is convert QByteArray to Base64.

```
return arr.toBase64();
```

Without Base64, I am receiving only NULL (/r/n) terminated string.